# Storing the color values of each pixel into a 2D array

Tags: java, image-processing, multidimensional-array, rgb, pixel

Is there a way to store the color of the pixel in the row and the column of an image into a 2D array.

I currently have this

```
 for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < w; j++) {
            int c = image1.getRGB(i, j);
     }
    }
```

But what I want to do is have c be like c[I][j] but getRGB does not work with arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure it works.

```
int[][] c = new int[w][h]

 for (int i = 0; i < w; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < h; j++) {
            c[i][j] = image1.getRGB(i, j);
     }
 }
```

Also, remember to switch height and width. Width should be the outer loop and height should be the inner one.

Comment: @Sherin From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB(int,%20int)) "An ArrayOutOfBoundsException may be thrown if the region is not in bounds. However, explicit bounds checking is not guaranteed." So you're trying to access pixels that aren't even part of the image

Comment: If I use `image1.getRGB(i, j);` I get an `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Coordinate out of bounds!` error but if use `image1.getRGB(j, i);` theres no error. Why is that?